# When will my version of Spring Web Services reach End of Life (EOL)?

Tags: spring-ws, eol

In various projects, I am using versions 2.0.2 and 2.1.4 of Spring Web Services. Given that neither of these are listed any longer on the project page at spring.io (http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) I am thinking that they're past EOL. Can anyone confirm, or better yet, provide a link to the official EOL announcement/schedule for Spring Web Services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! Since Spring reorganized their web site (quite some time back now, but this is a really old question), it's much more obvious: https://spring.io/projects/spring-ws#support.